# Detailed badge descriptions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges, design, information-display

Many badges have ambiguous or non-definitive descriptions (I think). I agree on keeping them short & simple, but, for the curious (& cunning) minds out there, can't we just **put a link** to [this awesome detailed answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) at the end of the [Help page describing all the badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges)? Just a thought.

OR

Another proposal will be **expandable descriptions**. If the user feels he needs more clarification on a particular badge, he could just click on the badge description which could expand & display all the implementation details.

OR

An **expandable icon tooltip** (suggested by sha-wiz-dow-ard)
[image]

The basic aim here is to make the search for mechanics/clarifications of badges easier. So, obviously, any other methods are welcome too!

Comment: At the end? No, that's bad UI design (at least in my opinion). Just above the list of badges would be better.

Comment: Updated with another proposal - "expandable descriptions"

Comment: There is one major flaw in this. The [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/152859) is maintained by ordinary users. Each user with only 100 reputation [can edit it at will](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki). This means that it might contain wrong information and even spam for short periods of time (clever spammer can reach 100+ rep across all sites, it happened before) so linking officially to this is too risky. Only when [meta-tag:faq] questions will more protected/monitored such idea will be feasible in my opinion.

Comment: Hmm, so maybe just do the expandable descriptions then!?

Comment: @AshishNitinPatil yes, I would add small icon next to each badge in the [badges page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) that when hovered will show full explanation. [Rough mockup](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sMTDj.png) - feel free to embed into your post. The full explanation won't be taken live from the faq entry but rather be "hard coded", same like the other text on the page.

Comment: Why do you keep editing with minor and meaningless edits all the time?

Comment: Sorry, won't do it from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for the beginners like me (of course) the suggestion that you have for Stack Overflow is the best suggestion ever. How?

Because it gives them a detail of how to earn such badges, what their achievement level is (bronze, silver, gold) how can one get them and how many times they are awarded. I had some issues while understanding which badge is achieved by which method.

But since I started exploring the site, and earning rep and indirectly some badges too. I felt that the way they're exposing the badges [a badge image; with achievement type (silver or other) and a simple but to the point description] is the best and the only method that can be used here.

Please note that: People come here to earn points but when they become a member of community. They come here to help others!

Which means that, it doesn't matter lets say for [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) of what type of badges he is having and what is the achievement level for him! Believe me, you'll get used to of this. :)

Comment: I know that the badges do *not* matter much, but, as you correctly said, the detailed descriptions should be easily available.

Comment: You're right. Stack Overflow should try to let the users with low rep or lets say new users easily learn what badges are so let them have some info in detail As well as for the users will enough rep shorten it down to the current one. What do you say?

Comment: The expandable descriptions is a good UI choice I hope.

Comment: For newbies it might be helpfull after all!